# Do I have to registerDoParallel() and stopCluster() every time I want to use foreach() in R?

Tags: r, parallel-processing, doparallel

I read you had to use `stopCluster()` after running parallel function: `foreach()` in R. However, I can get away with `registerDoParallel()` and then running `foreach()` as many times as I want without ever using `stopCluster()`. So do I need `stopCluster()` or not?

Does not using `stopCluster()` mean your cores are occupied with your current task? So if I am using parallel programming with only a little bit of single core sequential tasks in between, then I don't need to `stopCluster()`? I understand there are also significant overhead time consumption with setting up parallel.

Comment: I think leaving the cluster running while you do a little bit of non-parallel work in between is fine, as long as you stop the cluster at the end of your script/after all parallel processing is finished.

Answer (score 12):

`parallel::makeCluster()` and `doParallel::registerDoParallel()` create a set of copies of R running in parallel. The copies are called *workers*.

`parallel::stopCluster()` and `doParallel::stopImplicitCluster()` are safe ways of shutting down the workers. From the help page `?stopCluster`:

> It is good practice to shut down the workers by calling ‘stopCluster’: however the workers will terminate themselves once the socket on which they are listening for commands becomes unavailable, which it should if the master R session is completed (or its process dies).

Indeed, CPU usage of unused workers is often negligible. However, if the workers load large R objects, e.g., large datasets, they may use large parts of the memory and, as a consequence, slow down computations. In that case, it is more efficient to shut down the unused workers.

Comment: FYI, in [future](https://cran.r-project.org/package=future) 1.10.0 (disclaimer: I'm the author), I added support for automatic garbage collection of non-used clusters/workers.  Replacing `cl <- parallel::makeCluster(...)` with `cl <- future::makeClusterPSOCK(..., autoStop = TRUE)` will cause R to call `stopCluster()` automatically if variable `cl` has been removed, e.g. from `rm(cl)` or was only a local variable in a function.  Nothing magic, just an added feature to make life a tad easier. (I'll probably make `autoStop = TRUE` the default later).